# How to search using a domain class instance?

Tags: grails, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I have a domain class *User* with all the instances like

```
[User : 1, User: 2, User : 3, User:4, User: 5, User: 6, User: 7, ...]
```

and an instance list *userInstanceList* with only a few objects, say

```
[User : 3, User:4]
```

My *search term* is in *User : 4* and also in some other objects in *User*. When I search using

```
User.search(userInstanceList, searchTerm)
```

it returns all the objects in *User* with the *searchTerm*. How can I search objects only in *userInstanceList*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what userInstance is supposed to be in this case. Are you saying UserInstance is a subclass of User or are you just saying userInstance is a list holding a few specific instances of User?

Comment: It's a list holding specific User instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the search to only the things in the userInstanceList, you should be able to just use the `in` clause when searching.

```
User.findAll { 
   searchTerm && id in userInstanceList*.id
}
```

or

```
User.withCriteria {
    searchTerm
    inList id, userInstanceList*.id
}
```

Comment: I used _resultListFromSearch.findAll{it.id in userInstance*.id}_ to return a list containing common objects.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about suggesting that but I assumed you wanted to actually query the database again for some reason. Obviously searching the in-memory list is the better option from a performance standpoint.